# set column to insert extat charachter in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to insert char (A) in second index  where code start with 's'

Input
s1
s2
s34

Require output
sA1
sA2
sA34

```
Update T1
set code = ??
where code like 's%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Update T1
set code = 'sA' + SUBSTRING(code, 2, LEN(code)-1 )
where code like 's%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update MyTable
Set Code = Stuff(Code, 2, 0, 'A')
Where Code Like 's%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET  myColumn = 'sA' + RIGHT(myColumn, LEN(myColumn)-1)
WHERE LEFT(LOWER(myColumn), 1) = 's'
```

Comment: all colums set to sA where condition satisfied

Comment: @NETQuestion: feel free to give upvotes to all who helped answer your question!